# Check if stored procedure is running

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to check if a stored procedure or query is still running in SQL Server?

**Ideas**

1. I've thought of having a log where to write when the procedure starts and delete when it ends.

   *Flaws:*

   - it leaves open the case when the server restarts or some kind of failure inside the procedure.
   - this method needs some work to be done before running the procedure, so it can't be applied on already running procedures.
2. Use process monitor

I would prefer a solution that can be incorporated as a stored procedure with `procedure_name` and/or `pid`, `parameters` as input, so tracing programs or solutions using the SQL Server interface won't work.

### Update #1

---

Usage example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty 
    @time_str varchar(50)
AS 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   WAITFOR DELAY @time_str;
GO

dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty '00:00:10'
dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty '00:00:20'
dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty '00:00:30'
```

the procedure should be called like

```
test_if_running 'dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty '00:00:20''
```

and return true while running (for 20 seconds) and false after or if the function fails or the system is restarted

Comment: a real world example is when more users or procedures use a stored procedure that can't be used in the same time and checking if the procedure is already running is a must

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might query  `sys.dm_exec_requests` which will provide sesion_ID, waittime and futher rows of interest and CROSS APPLY `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` filtering your query with the SQL for your procedure.

```
Select * from
(
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
where sql_handle is not null
) a 
CROSS APPLY  sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) t 
where t.text like 'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty%'
```

Comment: works, but I'm curious why is the sql_text `CREATE PROCEDURE ..` ?

Comment: If you filter for `%dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty%` only you will find your own query shown above too, since it is containing dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty, you might find another way to avoid this. e.g. `where t.text like '%dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty%' and a.session_ID<>@@SPID`

Comment: understood, but I'll make tests before starting the procedure so it's fine, I was just curious what the column t.text represents

Answer (score 21):

**Update:** The answer given by John Clayton references the [outdated SQL Server 2000 system table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (sys.sysprocesses). The updated SQL is:

```
SELECT
  object_name(st.objectid) as ProcName
FROM
  sys.dm_exec_connections as qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.most_recent_sql_handle) st 
WHERE
  object_name(st.objectid) is not null
```

The SQL code above returns a list of names of your running processes. Note that you will [need permission to view the Server/Database state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions).

Comment: It seems this query returns the name of running processes *server wide*, not just on the database it's run on. This might or might not be intended behaviour depending on the use case, but it's good to be aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

```
exec sp_who2
```

It returns all db activities.

you will check from this proc if your procedure currently running or not.

Also will try that :

```
 SELECT  creation_time , object_name(st.objectid) as ProcName
        ,last_execution_time
        ,total_physical_reads
        ,total_logical_reads 
        ,total_logical_writes
        , execution_count
        , total_worker_time
        , total_elapsed_time
        , total_elapsed_time / execution_count avg_elapsed_time
        ,SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
         ((CASE statement_end_offset
          WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
          ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END
            - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
ORDER BY total_elapsed_time / execution_count DESC;
```

Comment: nice, but it doesn't show the procedure name shows only the commands it's currently executing, could you give an example based on the `sp_sleeping_beauty` example ?

Comment: the second solution doesn't show the procedure name, seems to only work for queries

Comment: check Now second column gives you Procedure Name

Comment: `dbo.sp_sleeping_beauty '00:00:20'`, used `object_name(st.objectid) LIKE '%sp_sleeping_beauty%'` and no go ...

Answer (score 4):

Old thread but you can do this,

```
SELECT @object = object_id
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE NAME = [SP NAME]

Select *
from        (
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
where sql_handle is not null
)                                              a
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) t
where objectid = @object
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to figure out how to do get the list of running procedures and came across this thread. After a bit of research on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189497.aspx) I was able to figure out the following query that will provide the list of running processes:

```
select 
  object_name(st.objectid) as ProcName 
from 
  sys.sysprocesses as qs 
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st 
where 
  object_name(st.objectid) is not null
```

A little bit more work will be needed to get the parameters.