# Get the handle of the currently executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm looking for a way to identify if a specific instance of a stored procedure is running.

For instance, let's say I have a procedure, foo, that is known to run for some lengthy period of time. I start foo as a part of process A and a little bit later start a separate instance of foo as part of process B. (The process could be any external thing kicking off that stored procedure.)

Later on, I want to be able to see if foo is running, but I want to see specifically if the instance of foo that was kicked off under process A is still running.

I've seen a number of solutions for checking if any instance of a sproc is running, but haven't seen anything regarding a specific instance.

Here's kindof what I was hoping for in magic fakey code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO fooWorkLog (handle)
    VALUES (@@MagicValueTellingMeTheSpecificHandleOfThisInstanceOfTheSproc)

    -- do other stuff
END

-- One Process does this

EXEC foo --let's say we know this has handle 123

-- Meanwhile another process does this

EXEC foo --let's say we know this has handle 789

-- A little bit later, from a different process
DECLARE @TheHandleImLookingFor INT = 123
SELECT ActiveHandle FROM SqlServersListOfActiveHandles
WHERE ActiveHandle = @TheHandleImLookingFor
```

Any ideas?

**More Info**

The following SO post is similar to what I'm asking [Check if stored procedure is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846306/check-if-stored-procedure-is-running)

However, unless I'm mistaken, that solution tells you that the sproc is running, but it does not tell me if the instance of the sproc that is running is the instance that was executed in a specific context.

Using their solution let's say if I started a sproc from one context (A), then started the sproc again from a different context (B). Some period of time later let's say just one of those two instances remained running. If I follow the example from the other post, it would tell me that the sproc was indeed currently running, but it would not tell me if it was sproc from context A or sproc from context B.

I may be mistaken, but I thought each time sql server executed a sproc it gave each instance a handle id of some sort. I was wondering if there was a way of identifying the handle that a sproc is running under and storing that handle in a table somewhere for reference.

If I'm not being clear yet, I can try again with another example.

Comment: you can use new guid() which is unique when insert and give clear seperation between 2 process

Comment: give some more details question is not clear.

Comment: @sandeeprawat I've added some more explaination, but might not be clear yet. Let me know if you want a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know hot to get the procedure handle, but a workaround for you is to write your own control.

If you have a table to store the process information, lets say "tb_ProcedureControl" you can insert a record when the procedure starts and then you set the end date when the procedure finishes.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
   @param1...
  ,@param2...
  ,@InstanceInfo = NULL --Optional parameter
AS
BEGIN
   --create the record for the instance
   INSERT INTO tb_ProcedureControl (InstanceInfo, Start, End) VALUES (@InstanceInfo, getdate(), null)   


    <TASK TO DO>

   --set the end of the process
   UPDATE tb_ProcedureControl SET End = GETDATE()
   WHERE InstanceInfo = @InstanceInfo

END
```